# Convert and modify ruby hash to new hash

Tags: ruby, hash

How could I convert my hash to 2 very different hashes?

**My hash:**

```
{ "grey"=> ["421_01.jpg", "421_02.jpg", "421_03.jpg"], 
  "heather blue"=> ["422_01.jpg", "422_02.jpg", "422_03.jpg"],
  "indigo"=> [], 
  "dark grey"=> ["435_01.jpg", "435_02.jpg", "435_03.jpg"] }
```

**1. Desired hash:** (all values from my hash)

```
[{ src: "421_01.jpg" },
 { src: "421_02.jpg" }, 
 { src: "421_03.jpg" }, 
 { src: "422_01.jpg" }, 
 { src: "422_02.jpg" }, 
 { src: "422_03.jpg" }, 
 { src: "435_01.jpg" }, 
 { src: "435_02.jpg" }, 
 { src: "435_03.jpg" }]
```

**2. Desired hash:**

```
[{
   image: "421_01.jpg, 421_02.jpg, 421_03.jpg",
   attributes: [
     {
       name: "Color",
       option: "grey"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   image: "422_01.jpg, 422_02.jpg, 422_03.jpg",
   attributes: [
     {
       name: "Color",
       option: "heather blue"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   image: "",
   attributes: [
     {
       name: "Color",
       option: "indigo"
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   image: "435_01.jpg, 435_02.jpg, 435_03.jpg",
   attributes: [
     {
       name: "Color",
       option: "dark grey"
     }
   ]
 }]
```

Please note: empty array in my hash shouldn't add any images to color variation, but should add variation with empty image string. (All shown in examples)

Comment: Asking for JSON format makes the question complex in a non-interesting way. Conversion between Ruby-JSON can be done easily with a library. If you really don't know how to do that, you should ask that as a separate question. Here, you should stick to Ruby objects.

Comment: Ok, sorry, thank you, sawa!

Answer (score 2):

```
h = { "grey"=> ["421_01.jpg", "421_02.jpg", "421_03.jpg"], 
      "heather blue"=> ["422_01.jpg", "422_02.jpg", "422_03.jpg"],
      "indigo"=> [], 
      "dark grey"=> ["435_01.jpg", "435_02.jpg", "435_03.jpg"] }

a = h.values
  #=> [["421_01.jpg", "421_02.jpg", "421_03.jpg"],
  #    ["422_01.jpg", "422_02.jpg", "422_03.jpg"],
  #    [],
  #    ["435_01.jpg", "435_02.jpg", "435_03.jpg"]]
```

For #1:

```
a.flat_map { |s| { src: s } }
  #=> [{:src=>"421_01.jpg"}, {:src=>"421_02.jpg"}, {:src=>"421_03.jpg"},
  #    {:src=>"422_01.jpg"}, {:src=>"422_02.jpg"}, {:src=>"422_03.jpg"},
  #    {:src=>"435_01.jpg"}, {:src=>"435_02.jpg"}, {:src=>"435_03.jpg"}]
```

For #2:

```
 h.map { |k,_| { image: a.shift.join(', '),
                 attributes: [{ name: "Color", option: k }] } }
  # => [{:image=>"421_01.jpg, 421_02.jpg, 421_03.jpg",
         :attributes=>[{:name=>"Color", :option=>"grey"}]},
        {:image=>"422_01.jpg, 422_02.jpg, 422_03.jpg",
         :attributes=>[{:name=>"Color", :option=>"heather blue"}]},
        {:image=>"", :attributes=>[{:name=>"Color", :option=>"indigo"}]},
        {:image=>"435_01.jpg, 435_02.jpg, 435_03.jpg",
         :attributes=>[{:name=>"Color", :option=>"dark grey"}]}]
```

Comment: @sawa's, thanks for the suggestion. I edited to incorporate it. It simplified #2 as well as #1.

Comment: I see @santosh and I have essentially the same answers. For the record, I had his #1 before incorporating sawa's comment, but he posted his answer before I did an edit to add #2, and then subsequently changed it slightly. Clearly, we both developed our answers independently.